# Twitter Fabric get recent tweets by a user

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm new to using Fabric to access the Twitter app. I have Fabric running with Swift and I can make the basic requests for feeds.

```
self.dataSource = TWTRCollectionTimelineDataSource(collectionID: "393773266801659904", APIClient: client)
```

However I am not seeing anywhere to make a custom request. Specifically I want to request the recent tweets by an account. Example: @Jack last 20 tweets

How would I do this in swift? thanks